# How to use 1 formula to Count items by date?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, gspread

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_b-wdVQFKKSpJtNF4coNhQvmv20mUFSGkpppbOTE9Cg/edit?usp=sharing

Hi, I am trying to build a report. How can I write 1 formula at B2 to count the SKUs by date?   Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Hi be careful if your spreadsheet contains real people's data you just gave it away on internet with no restrictions.

Comment: Please clarify your question, "counting SKUs by date" is not clear. You can count items or you can group items by date. Or may be you meant something more complex like "count how many SKUs exist for each date" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my added sheet ("Erik Help"). The formula in B2:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"")&"~"&FILTER(B1:1,B1:1<>""),QUERY({Data!D2:D&"~"&Data!A2:A},"Select Col1, COUNT(Col1) GROUP BY Col1"),2,FALSE)))`

The `FILTER`s aren't strictly necessary, but they will speed up processing, especially if you have a lot of data in your real sheet.

Every element from A2:A (the SKUs) is concatenated with a tilde `~` and then every element of B1:1 (the dates).

`QUERY` forms a two-column grouping of each SKU~date and `COUNT` of each from the Data sheet.

`VLOOKUP` then acts on every element of the virtual array grid, trying to find it within the `QUERY`. If found, the `COUNT` is returned. If not, `IFERROR` returns null.